# Java JSerialComm writing not writing?

Tags: java, netbeans, serial-port

I have a java application that uses JSerialComm imported through the POM.xml file. I have my connect code as follows:

```
public void connectPort(int index) {
    System.out.println("Attempting to connect to Index:" + index);
    int baudRate = 115200;
            
    SerialPort comPort = comPortList[index];
    currentConnectedPort = comPort;
    comPort.openPort();
    comPort.setParity(SerialPort.NO_PARITY);
    comPort.setNumStopBits(SerialPort.ONE_STOP_BIT);
    comPort.setNumDataBits(8);
    comPort.addDataListener(this);
    comPort.setBaudRate(baudRate);
            
    System.out.println("Connection successful!");
    updateStatus("Connected!");
}
```

This seems to work as it triggers my listener every 5 seconds as expected from the device it connects to. I can read the data the device outputs however I cannot for the life of me write stuff to the device.
In PuttY I can simply type "boxtest start 0 -3000" and then press enter and the thing starts the process that is the boxtest, however on my Java app when I write to the serial port nothing happens, the machine doesnt respond at all and I dont know if I'm missing something.

Here's my write code:

```
public void writeToPort(String cmd) {
    if(cmd.equals("about")) {
        String thisVersion;
        thisVersion = String.format("Current version is %s", currentVersion);
        updateStatus(thisVersion);
    } else if(!cmd.isEmpty()){
        System.out.printf("Command received: ' %s ', Writing to Serial Port", cmd);
    parseData(cmd);
    //Convert the string to a byte array
    byte b[] = cmd.getBytes();
        currentConnectedPort.writeBytes(b, b.length);
        System.out.println("\n ********** ");
        System.out.println("Lenght is: " + b.length);
        System.out.println("Wrote: " + currentConnectedPort.writeBytes(cmd.getBytes(), cmd.length()) + " bytes");
        System.out.println(" ********** \n");
    updateStatus("Command Sent");
}
```

}

From what I read writeBytes returns an int of the amount of bytes it wrote and my output confirms it technically wrote the 21 bytes I requested, but the receiving device doesnt do anything. (with PuttY it does, with Java it doesnt).

The output is as follows:

```
Command received: ' boxtest start 0 -3000 ', Writing to Serial PortParsing Input: boxtest start 0 -3000 
 logging is true 
received values string

 ********** 
Lenght is: 21
Wrote: 21 bytes
 **********
```

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added code to more completely clarify my code and hopefully explain my issue better

Comment: You have removed your error stacktrace, I would start with fixing that, or removing that part of code from your test.